# gnome-software: Could not activate remote peer

Tags: rhel, gnome, software-updates, flatpak, alma-linux

When I open `gnome-software` I get the following error:

[image: error]

I've looked at the verbose output from the app, but understand nothing:

```
$ echo '# kill existing processes'; killall gnome-software; echo '# done killing'; gnome-software --verbose 2>&1 | grep -C7 'not handling error failed for action'
# kill existing processes
gnome-software: no process found
# done killing
08:12:38:0806 Gs  Chaining cancellation from 0x560efce97e20 to 0x560efd0f8820
08:12:38:0806 Gs  Chaining cancellation from 0x560efce97e20 to 0x560efd0fa160
08:12:38:0806 Gs  Chaining cancellation from 0x560efce97e20 to 0x560efd17a9e0
08:12:38:0806 Gs  Disconnecting cancellable 0x560efce97e20
08:12:38:0806 Gs  emitting global finished
08:12:38:0807 Gs  getting historical updates for fresh session
08:12:38:0807 Gs  Chaining cancellation from 0x560efcf592a0 to 0x560efd17a820
08:12:38:0807 Gs  not handling error failed for action refresh: Could not activate remote peer.
08:12:38:0807 Gs  emitting global waiting
08:12:38:0807 Gs  emitting waiting(packagekit-refresh)
08:12:38:0807 Gs  emitting waiting(packagekit-refresh)
08:12:38:0807 Gs  emitting waiting(packagekit-refresh)
08:12:38:0807 Gs  emitting setup(packagekit-refresh)
08:12:38:0807 Gs  emitting global finished
08:12:38:0808 Gs  not handling error failed for action get-updates-historical: Could not activate remote peer.
08:12:38:0809 Gs  truncating results to 20 from 59
08:12:38:0809 Gs  no ->sort_func() set for get-featured, using random!
08:12:38:0812 PK  role now resolve
08:12:38:0816 Gs  emitting global waiting
08:12:38:0827 Gs  running get-updates-historical on plugin=packagekit with dedupe-flags=7 with refine-flags=require-version with timeout=60 on apps , elapsed time since creation 20ms
08:12:38:0830 GsPluginFlatpak system/flatpak/flathub/org.gnucash.GnuCash/stable is not installed, so ignoring version of 4.13+ (Flathub 4.13)
08:12:38:0831 GsPluginFlatpak marking system/flatpak/flathub/org.gnucash.GnuCash/stable as available with flatpak
^C
```

adding `strace` to the mix I see the word 'peer' again in the `getpeername` syscalls right before the errors - leading me to believe that the software is actually handling something that is not as a 'peer'.

```
$ echo '# kill existing processes'; killall gnome-software; echo '# done killing'; strace gnome-software --verbose 2>&1 | grep -C7 'not handling error failed for action'
# kill existing processes
gnome-software: no process found
# done killing
futex(0x5576ba937d80, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x5576ba9689e0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x5576ba961088, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
getpeername(2, 0x7ffc63195d80, [128])   = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7ffc63195d80)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
write(2, "08:15:52:0916 ", 1408:15:52:0916 )          = 14
write(2, "Gs  ", 4Gs  )                     = 4
write(2, "not handling error failed for ac"..., 78not handling error failed for action refresh: Could not activate remote peer.
) = 78
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
--
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
getpeername(2, 0x7ffc63195d80, [128])   = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7ffc63195d80)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
write(2, "08:15:52:0924 ", 1408:15:52:0924 )          = 14
write(2, "Gs  ", 4Gs  )                     = 4
write(2, "not handling error failed for ac"..., 93not handling error failed for action get-updates-historical: Could not activate remote peer.
) = 93
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7f20427bd108, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
^C
```

I've done `rm -rf ~/.cache/` but it has not affected the problem. I've tried toggling some sources on and off again, error remains.

Is this a bug with the software? Or is there some other config I can tweak do stop the failing operation?

I'm on

```
$ gnome-software --version
gnome-software 41.5
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
AlmaLinux release 9.1 (Lime Lynx)
$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…
Nothing to do.
$ dnf check-update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:28:59 ago on Tue 17 Jan 2023 09:00:15 AM CET.
```

I went through the entire list of repos and disabled them all - that made the error disappear. When I re-enabled `flathub` only the error came back. Disabling `flathub` but enabling all relevant package repos there is no error - so only flathub is causing the problem.

[image: flathub bad]